# JQuery Auto Complete without www (in url) not working, but with www is working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, dns

I am working on asp.net c# project and when I type url name like this: http://mydomain.com Jquery auto Complete doesn't work and gives error message but when I add www to it like this: www.mydomain.com it works...

Any Idea..?

Error Message :-

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mydomain.com/AutoComplete.asmx/GetAutoCompleteData. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

Comment: Three words: same origin policy

Comment: @DownVoters - Who down voted this? It's a well structured question. You don't down vote because a question is simple!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`www.example.com` and `example.com` are [different origins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and you can't ([FSVO can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)) use JavaScript running on one to request data from the other.

Use a relative URI in your JavaScript, not an absolute one.

It would also be a good idea to run your site from one hostname, instead of two similar ones. Pick either `www.example.com` or `example.com` to be your canonical hostname and set up the other to redirect its traffic to it.

Comment: button click also not working..give error Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 0

Comment: @HarshitTailor — That's an entirely different problem, for which you haven't given enough information to solve. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're being caught by the Same Origin Policy.

My guess is you've hardcoded the link in the Autocomplete setup to `www.mydomain.com`, and when viewing the site view `mydomain.com` it counts as a cross-site request.

The solution is to make the AJAX request URL in the autocomplete setup relative.

Comment: button click also not working..give error Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 0

Comment: @HarshitTailor that's an issue with your server-side code. I'd start a new question about that.